# Unity3d Join and Separate two bodies

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am trying to do that child object should move together with its parent. Then after some time, it should become independent. And it should move according to its own rigidbody2D. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the parent of the child rigidbody to null in script:

```
transform.parent = null;
```

Reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html

Comment: I tried. The problem is that child object doesn't follow its parent at the beginning already because it has its own rigidbody2d.

Comment: I reckon you dragged the child under the parent in the Hierarchy view?

Comment: Yeah, I dragged the child under the parent. Both parent and child have rigidbodies.

Comment: on the other hand, if there is not any rigidbody attached to the child at the beginning, it becomes stable (naturally) when I set its parent to null.

Comment: Maybe create a joint between the 2 bodies, and break/remove that?